# How can remove keys with empty values in an Object Array in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I'm trying to write a function in my Angular 8 project. I have an Array of Objects and want to remove all key:value pairs where the value is empty. There are many examples on the internet but none of them seem to work for me.

What I have:

```
{
        "flightID": "FooID",
        "direction": "DownFoo",
        "msgType": "FooType",
        "elemNb": "",
        "msgID": "",
    },
    {
        "flightID": "FooID2",
        "direction": "UpFoo",
        "msgType": "FooType2",
        "elemNb": "",
        "msgID": "",
    },
```

What I want:

```
    {
        "flightID": "FooID",
        "direction": "DownFoo",
        "msgType": "FooType",
    },
    {
        "flightID": "FooID2",
        "direction": "UpFoo",
        "msgType": "FooType2",
    },
```

My attempt:

```
myList: any[]

 removeEmptyValues() {
    if (this.myList) {

      this.myList.forEach((value) => {

        Object.keys(value).forEach((key) => {
          delete key[''];

        })
      })
    }
    console.log(this.myList);
  }
```

I would expect that `delete key['']` would delete the key if the value is empty but it isn't doing anything. How can I delete the key if the value is empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try deleting value[key] instead of key['']

```
if (value[key] === '') {
  delete value[key];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var list = [{
        "flightID": "FooID",
        "direction": "DownFoo",
        "msgType": "FooType",
        "elemNb": "",
        "msgID": "",
    },
    {
        "flightID": "FooID2",
        "direction": "UpFoo",
        "msgType": "FooType2",
        "elemNb": "",
        "msgID": "",
}];

let result = Array.from(list, o=> Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).filter((i) => i[1] != (null || ''))));

console.log(result);
```

```
var list = [{
        "flightID": "FooID",
        "direction": "DownFoo",
        "msgType": "FooType",
        "elemNb": "",
        "msgID": "",
    },
    {
        "flightID": "FooID2",
        "direction": "UpFoo",
        "msgType": "FooType2",
        "elemNb": "",
        "msgID": "",
}];

let result = Array.from(list, o=> Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).filter((i) => i[1] != (null || ''))));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the key from object

```
myList: any[]

 removeEmptyValues() {
    if (this.myList) {

      this.myList.forEach((value) => {

        Object.keys(value).forEach((key) => {
          delete this.myList[key]

        })
      })
    }
    console.log(this.myList);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to check if the value is empty and remove the key. They the below code.

```
myList: any[]

removeEmptyValues() {
  if (this.myList) {

    this.myList.forEach((value) => {

      Object.keys(value).forEach((key) => {
        if(!value[key]) delete value[key];
      })
    })
  }
  console.log(this.myList);
}
```